# Fighting Two Specific Issues on Screen Orientation Change (Android)

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I know you can use this: android:configChanges="orientation"  to eliminate redraws on orientation changes.  Although it does not in my app.  I've read that there may be a method you need to override with it to make it work.  But I think that may be overkill.

There are only two issues I do not want to happen when I rotate the screen from portrait to landscape (or the other way).

1. If the user touches an EditText, keyboard pops up.  You shift orientations, and it auto-hides.  I want to keep the soft keyboard along for the ride.
2. I have a ListView loading data populated from a MySQL database.  It does this through an AsynTask.  When I switch orientations, I do not want this task to be called.

**Can I isolate these two issues, or is the first option (configChanges) the answer?**

Note:  A couple of these are List Activities; but the big one is a FragmentActivity with Viewpager, and a Fragment / ListFRagment (with tabs) inner class inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the orientation changes the Activity is destroyed and recreated.  The method you would override if using `configChanges` is `onConfigurationChanged`.

For the keyboard question, sounds like you just need to keep a track of it's state and restore it via the `Bundle` passed in `Activity.onCreate`.

For the second question, you could check if `onSavedInstanceState == null` to determine if you need to run the `AsyncTask`.  You will need to save any data to the `Bundle` in `onPause`.